# Show function data without blinking with Volley in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Recently I am working on Android project with Volley for registration and for further operation, I can make function for insertion and other one is for retrieval data. When insert button click 'Insert' function called and data has been inserted to database through volley, and at the same time retrieval function also called. But when USER clicked the button and function called then data showed(database inserted data) with blinking effect, look like loading.

I want to get rid of that effect. I want to show data smoothly without any blinking effect. I do searching but can not find any solution. Please suggest me solution I'am newbie so kindly short and efficient required.

```
package com.darkcoderz.parsejson;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Context mContext;
private Activity mActivity;

//private CoordinatorLayout mCLayout;
private TextView mTextView;
private String mJSONURLString = "http://192.168.10.4/volley/api.php";
String url = "http://192.168.10.4/volley/register.php";
private EditText sms;
private Button sendsms;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get the application context
    //mContext = getApplicationContext();
    //mActivity = MainActivity.this;

    // Get the widget reference from XML layout
    //mCLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    sms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sms);
    sendsms = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendsms);


    final Handler firesms = new Handler();
    firesms.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getdata();
            firesms.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    });

    sendsms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            reg();
        }
    });

    getdata();
}

 //    insert
  public void reg()
 {
final String msg = sms.getText().toString();
StringRequest stringreq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        if (response.equals("success"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registration Successfull!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username Already Exist!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Great Error "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
})
{
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("sms",msg);
        return params;
    }
};
RequestQueue reqest = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
reqest.add(stringreq);
```

}

```
private void getdata() {

            // Empty the TextView
            mTextView.setText("");

            // Initialize a new RequestQueue instance
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

            // Initialize a new JsonArrayRequest instance
            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, mJSONURLString, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    // Do something with response
                    //mTextView.setText(response.toString());

                    // Process the JSON
                    try{
                        // Loop through the array elements
                        for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                            // Get current json object
                            JSONObject student = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Get the current student (json object) data
             //                                String firstName = student.getString("fname");
                //                                String lastName = student.getString("lname");
                            String age = student.getString("email");

                            // Display the formatted json data in text view
                            mTextView.append("SMS : " + age);
                            mTextView.append("\n\n");
                        }
                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
                    new Response.ErrorListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                            // Do something when error occurred

                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Something Went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
            );

            // Add JsonArrayRequest to the RequestQueue
            requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

}
```

}

Comment: Please add some code so that we can narrow down on what the problem is. The 'blinking effect' is not something Android does, so it should be due to how you are loading and displaying information from your database .

Comment: @TheGamer007 I updated my code, kindly check it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void getdata() {

        // Empty the TextView
        mTextView.setText("");

        // Initialize a new RequestQueue instance
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        // Initialize a new JsonArrayRequest instance
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, mJSONURLString, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                //before parsing check your response is in JSONArray Format or JSONObject format
                // Process the JSON
                try{

                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                   //print here to know JSONException if exists 
                   Toast.makeText(mContext, "Exception"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                        // Do something when error occurred

                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Something Went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        );

        // Add JsonArrayRequest to the RequestQueue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
   }
```

Comment: If we can not use for loop in try block then data can't b printout on screen...For loop shows the returned data

Comment: use `Log` to see the output

Comment: Can not get any response and also show error that JSONException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement...

Comment: @DarkCoder what's the result that your expecting in the response before to parse and how is it if you change `JsonArrayRequest` to `StringRequest` to get the response as string and then convert it to JSON if its vali